# Asking to remove the time in datetime without changing the datatype

Tags: sql-server

I want to ask about this one

[image]

1. How to remove the time in "Tanggal" column, without changing its datatype?
2. How to remove the 2 last digit 0 in "Harga" column?

Thank you

Comment: Both of these issues are display settings and should be done in the front end, not at the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dateadd()` to truncate the time portion like so:

```
dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, b.Tanggal), 0) as Tanggal
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some negative values in the "Harga" column you should use a combination of FLOOR() and CEILING() functions instead of FLOOR(Harga).

```
declare @q TABLE
(
    Tanggal DATETIME,
    Harga   MONEY
)

INSERT @q
VALUES
('2014-02-02', 1200000),
('2013-02-02', 1200000),
('2013-02-02', 1200000),
('2014-12-29 16:25:53.000', 1200000)

SELECT CAST(Tanggal AS DATE) AS Tanggal, 
  CAST(FLOOR(Harga) AS INT) AS Harga
FROM @q
```